# Sign up with Facebook and create Auth0 account

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, auth0

Is it possible to create a user on auth0 using a 'sign up with Facebook' button, i.e so they don't have to enter their email, password etc to sign up or login? I can't seem to find the appropriate API call in the Auth0 docs to do this. In the future I will probably add more options to my application (e.g. Google, Twitter, etc)

I know about and have used the [account linking request](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_identities) `POST /api/v2/users/{id}/identities` - this needs an existing Auth0 account to link to (which won't exist as I want to create the account from the Facebook request) - and the [user creating request](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#signup) `POST /dbconnections/signup`, but this only works for Database connections, not social connections.

One possible option I considered was combining the two requests above, i.e creating the account and then linking it to the user's Facebook/social profile, but this seems pretty cumbersome. Also, what would I set the password as? (required in the `POST /dbconnections/signup` request).

So what is the process for creating an auth0 user account using social signup?